Suppose I have a small number of prometheus compatible metrics timeseries stored in memory. How to execute a PromQL query against them?
I don't want the overhead for an entire Prometheus instance running on my k8s cluster.
I need to build a k8s custom metrics api implementation, which responds to requests from HorizontalPodAutoscalers. Let's say I already have the metrics series for which HPA will be expected to query. Can I use some open source library to represent them in an appropriate way so that I run a PromQL query against them locally and get the response I would expect? I guess I am interested in sum and rate functions and labels based matching.
I am open to other suggestions but the main constraints are that the data is already part of the same process which receives the custom metrics api request and I need to respond with the calculated value for the given window of time.

"I don't want the overhead for an entire Prometheus instance": I don't believe Prometheus introduces that much overhead if you're not feeding it a large number of metrics. I think the simplest path to a solution is "run prometheus and have it scrape your metrics"; then you can run any promql queries you want.

@larsks It still complicates the setup more than I would like and I am investigating how easy it would be to avoid that

Whatever you do besides use an open source TSDB databases such as Prometheus are going to complicate your set up. Especially if you depend on it for ongoing monitoring and alerting. Might as well learn and use a industry standard tool that have plenty of articles written about it.
